# c# datatable groupby and sum column's values (without know the name)

Tags: c#, linq

I need to do a group by and sum the values for each columns. Actually I've been able to create a datatable as:

```
DataTable stats = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r["Data"]).OrderByDescending(r => r.Key).Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r["Data"]).First()).CopyToDataTable();
```

Basically I need also to sum each values for each columns in the original datatable (dt). Please consider that, apart a couple of columns, I might dunno how many they are and its name.
In a previous test I used:

```
var query = from stat in stats
            group stat by stat.Field<string>("Data") into data
            orderby data.Key
            select new
            {
                Data = data.Key,
                TotTWorked = data.Sum(stat => stat.Field<int>("Time_Work")),
                TotTHold = data.Sum(stat => stat.Field<int>("Time_Hold")),
                TotTAlarm = data.Sum(stat => stat.Field<int>("Time_Alarm")),
                Productivity = 0,
            };
```

But now I need to be more flexible so I can't specify the column name as above. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming you have at least the list of column names, I'd go with the approach of creating a dictionary as part of the select and then transform it later to whatever form you need it. Here's an example:

```
var query = from stat in stats
                        group stat by stat.Field<string>("Data") into data
                        orderby data.Key
                        select new
                        {
                            Data = data.Key,
                            SumsDictionary = listOfColumnNames
                                             .Select(colName => new { ColName = colName, Sum = data.Sum(stat => stat.Field<int>(colName)) })
                                             .ToDictionary(d => d.ColName, d => d.Sum),
                            Productivity = 0,
                        };
```

So that if you were to serialize the result object it would look something like this:

```
{
  "Data": {},
  "SumsDictionary": {
    "Time_Work": 10,
    "Time_Hold": 20,
    "Time_Alarm": 30
  },
  "Productivity": 0
}
```

Hope it helps!